# Logstash-Forwader 3.1 state file .logstash-forwarder not updating

Tags: elastic-stack, logstash-forwarder

I am having an issue with Logstash-forwarder 3.1.1 on Centos 6.5 where the state file /.logstash-forwarder is not updating as information is sent to Logstash.

I have found as activity is logged by logstash-forwarder the corresponding offset is not recorded in /.logstash-forwarder 'logrotate' file. The ./logstash-forwarder file is being recreated each time 100 events are recorded but not updated with data.  I know the file has been recreated because I changed permissions to test, and permissions are reset each time.

Below are my configurations (With some actual data italicized/scrubbed):
Logstash-forwarder 3.1.1
Centos 6.5

/etc/logstash-forwarder
*Note that the "paths" key does contain wildcards*

```
{
  "network": {
    "servers": [ "*server*:*port*" ],
    "timeout": 15,
    "ssl ca": "/*path*/logstash-forwarder.crt"
  },
  "files": [
    {
      "paths": [
        "/a/b/tomcat-*-*/logs/catalina.out"
       ],
      "fields": { "type": "apache", "time_zone": "EST" }
    }
   ]
}
```

Per logstash instructions for Centos 6.5 I have configured the LOGSTASH_FORWARDER_OPTIONS value so it looks like the following:

```
LOGSTASH_FORWARDER_OPTIONS="-config /etc/logstash-forwarder -spool-size 100"
```

Below is the resting state of the /.logstash-forwarder logrotate file:

```
{"/a/b/tomcat-set-1/logs/catalina.out":{"source":"/a/b/tomcat-set-1/logs/catalina.out","offset":433564,"inode":*number1*,"device":*number2*},"/a/b/tomcat-set-2/logs/catalina.out":{"source":"/a/b/tomcat-set-2/logs/catalina.out","offset":18782151,"inode":*number3*,"device":*number4*}}
```

There are two sets of logs that this is capturing.   The offset has stayed the same for 20 minutes while activities have been occurred and sent over to Logstash.

Can anyone give me any advice on how to fix this problem whether it be a configuration setting I missed or a bug?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After more research I found it was announced that Filebeats is the preferred forwarder of choice now.  I even found a post by the owner of Logstash-Forwarder that the program is full of bugs and is not fully supported any more.

I have instead moved to Centos7 using the latest version of the ELK stack, using Filbeats as the forwarder.  Things are going much smoother now!